# JavaScript form submit doesn't fire asp server-side click function of the submit button

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I used an event listener to prevent the action of my asp:button (submit) because I wanted to validate my form with a javascript function before it actually gets submitted.

```
formInstance.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
}, false);
```

Here is the button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCreateForm" CssClass="submit-form button" runat="server" 
    Text="Save Form" OnClick="btnCreateForm_Click" 
        OnClientClick="Sharpforms.checkFormEntry()" />
```

The fired javascript:

```
checkFormEntry: function () {
    var formName = document.getElementById("txtFormName");

    if (formName.value.trim() == "") {
        alert("Please fill in a valid form name!");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        //formInstance.submit();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Apparently the javascript submit() does submit the form because the page is being reloaded but I recognized that it doesn't enter my ASP side **btnCreateForm_Click** function any more:

```
protected void btnCreateForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Test if the button has been clicked.");
}
```

When commenting my form event listener as well as the submit() and try to submit it natively he enters the click function without problems. But then I have no possibility to check my form on the client side. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add return to the OnClientClick event. If the function returns true, the postback occurs. If the function returns false, the postback gets cancelled.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCreateForm" CssClass="submit-form button" runat="server" 
    Text="Save Form" OnClick="btnCreateForm_Click" 
        OnClientClick="return Sharpforms.checkFormEntry()" />
```

Also, doing it in this way you can remove the event listener.